# JAXB Binder.updateXml(objectTobeUpdated) fails when called twice

Tags: jaxb

I have an existing XML, im using Jaxb to update it. Following code fails: there are bugs raised on this issue, but couldnt get any information about the fix. Can anyone kindly help on how to resolve the issue.

```
    package la.te.st;

    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

    @XmlRootElement
    public class Student{

       String name;
       int age;
       int id;

       public String getName(){
          return name;
       }

       @XmlElement
       public void setName(String name){
          this.name = name;
       }

       public int getAge(){
          return age;
       }

       @XmlElement
       public void setAge(int age){
          this.age = age;
       }

       public int getId(){
          return id;
       }

       @XmlAttribute
       public void setId(int id){
          this.id = id;
       }

       @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.name + " age:" + this.age + " id:" + this.id;
        }
    }



/**************************************/

package la.te.st;


import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Binder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

public class BinderDemo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      try {
         // we need a blank document to store final xml output
         DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
         DocumentBuilder docBuilder = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
         Document document = docBuilder.parse("Student.xml");

         // create JAXBContext which will be used to create a Binder
         JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Student.class);

         Binder<Node> binder = jc.createBinder();

         // set output as formatted one
         binder.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

         // get xml node from the document
         Node xmlNode = document.getDocumentElement();

         // Returns the updated JAXB object
         Student st = (Student)binder.updateJAXB(xmlNode);

         System.out.println(st);
         // set age and name
         st.setAge(11);
         st.setName("Sania");

         System.out.println(st);
         // update xml node with new data
         xmlNode = binder.updateXML(st);

         st.setAge(12);
         st.setName("Sania");

         System.out.println(st);

         xmlNode = binder.updateXML(st);

         // set node value to the document
         document.setNodeValue(xmlNode.getNodeValue());

         // finally print the edited object on stdout
         TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
         Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();
         t.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(System.out));

      }catch(Exception ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}


/*****************************/

the Student.xml file :

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<student id="10">
   <age>10</age>
   <name>Zara Ali</name>
</student>
```

Comment: Which implementation/version of JAXB (JSR-222) are you using?  You could try using EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy):  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/jaxb-xml-infoset-preservation.html (Note:  I'm the MOXy lead)

Comment: I am not using MOXy, I was able to solve my problem using deep cloning, which im sure is not the best way to solve. But for those who are desperate to solve same kind of problem without going for MOXy following are the steps: 

1.Object o = binder.parse(xml);
2.edit object  o here
3. call binder.updateXML() api to update the xml
4. edit o again
5. (calling binder.updateXML() fails here) Object o1 = binder2.parse(xmlfile) , o1 will have latest changes
6. deep copy o in to o1 
7. binder2.updateXML() will update the xml without exception.